# Из jar в exe с автоматическим запуском консоли

Tags: java, jar, exe

Есть программа, которая работает через консоль. Обычно я запускаю jar файл через командную строку, но хочу, чтобы пользователь запустил exe файл и у него всплыла готовая консоль с запущенной программой. Использую Launch4j. Вылазит ошибка "an error occurred while starting application". Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[![введите сюда описание изображения][3]][3]

Answer (score 1):

На каком jdk сделан jar?
Упаковывающая программа из окружения берёт путь к jre?
Когда точно возникает ошибка?(запакаовка, исполнение запакованного в exe jar'а?)

Полагаю, можно поменять значение minJRE на значение версии Вашего JDK.
И добавить встроенный jre указав путь к имеющемуся в поле Bundled JRE path.

Можно так же воспользоваться bat файлом или bash скриптом, в котором просто прописать строчку
`java -jar MyAppliication.jar`

сделать скрипт исполняемым. Эффект будет почти как от упакованого jar'а.